# Transform Pandas DataFrame, add row values as column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
COMMIT_ID | FILE_NAME     | COMMITTER | CHANGE TYPE
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1       |  package.json | A         | MODIFY
  2       |  main.js      | B         | ADD
  2       |  class.java   | B         | DELETE
```

I want the row values of the file name as column headers and the changetype as the value.

```
COMMIT_ID | package.json | main.js     | class.java     | COMMITTER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1       |  MODIFY      |  NONE       |  NONE          | A         
  2       |  NONE        |  ADD        |  DELETE        | B
```

I have tried with `pandas.pivot_table` but wasn't very successful. Any chance to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['COMMIT_ID','COMMITTER','FILE_NAME'])['CHANGE TYPE']
       .unstack()
      .reset_index()
print (df)
FILE_NAME  COMMIT_ID COMMITTER class.java main.js package.json
0                  1         A       None    None       MODIFY
1                  2         B     DELETE     ADD         None
```

Solutions with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) - need aggregate function like `sum` (concatenate strings without separator) or `'_'.join` (concatenate strings with separator) if duplicates:

```
print (df)
   COMMIT_ID     FILE_NAME COMMITTER CHANGE TYPE
0          1  package.json         A      MODIFY
1          2       main.js         B         ADD
2          2    class.java         B      DELETE
3          2    class.java         B         ADD


df = df.pivot_table(index=['COMMIT_ID','COMMITTER'], 
                    columns='FILE_NAME', 
                    values='CHANGE TYPE', 
                    aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
print (df)
FILE_NAME  COMMIT_ID COMMITTER class.java main.js package.json
0                  1         A       None    None       MODIFY
1                  2         B  DELETEADD     ADD         None
```

Or:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['COMMIT_ID','COMMITTER'], 
                    columns='FILE_NAME', 
                    values='CHANGE TYPE', 
                    aggfunc='_'.join).reset_index()
print (df)
FILE_NAME  COMMIT_ID COMMITTER  class.java main.js package.json
0                  1         A        None    None       MODIFY
1                  2         B  DELETE_ADD     ADD         None
```

Aggregate with `first` works also, but you can lost duplicates values:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['COMMIT_ID','COMMITTER'], 
                    columns='FILE_NAME', 
                    values='CHANGE TYPE', 
                    aggfunc='first').reset_index()
print (df)
FILE_NAME  COMMIT_ID COMMITTER class.java main.js package.json
0                  1         A       None    None       MODIFY
1                  2         B     DELETE     ADD         None
```

Last for rename columns names add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   COMMIT_ID COMMITTER class.java main.js package.json
0          1         A       None    None       MODIFY
1          2         B  DELETEADD     ADD         None
```

Comment: Seriously doubt you are a Pandas Robot @jezrael.