# Pandas: encoding row values/transform dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transformation

This is a little similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998879/transform-pandas-dataframe-add-row-values-as-column-headers) but my problem is a little different.

My dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([{'date': '2017-01-01', 'id': 'google', 'category': 1, 'Score1': 51, 'Score2': 531},
         {'date': '2017-01-01', 'id': 'google', 'category': 2, 'Score1': 592, 'Score2': 152},
         {'date': '2017-01-01', 'id': 'google', 'category': 5, 'Score1': 55, 'Score2': 255},
         {'date': '2017-01-01', 'id': 'yahoo', 'category': 7, 'Score1': 597, 'Score2': 357},
         {'date': '2017-01-01', 'id': 'yahoo', 'category': 8, 'Score1': 58, 'Score2': 58},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'id': 'google', 'category': 5, 'Score1': 795, 'Score2': 455},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'id': 'google', 'category': 1, 'Score1': 71, 'Score2': 751},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'id': 'google', 'category': 2, 'Score1': 792, 'Score2': 352},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'id': 'yahoo', 'category': 7, 'Score1': 77, 'Score2': 957},
         {'date': '2017-01-02', 'id': 'yahoo', 'category': 8, 'Score1': 798, 'Score2': 358}
       ])
```

And looks like this:

```
         date      id  category  Score1  Score2
0  2017-01-01  google         1      51     531
1  2017-01-01  google         2     592     152
2  2017-01-01  google         5      55     255
3  2017-01-01   yahoo         7     597     357
4  2017-01-01   yahoo         8      58      58
5  2017-01-02  google         5     795     455
6  2017-01-02  google         1      71     751
7  2017-01-02  google         2     792     352
8  2017-01-02   yahoo         7      77     957
9  2017-01-02   yahoo         8     798     358
```

I need to transform this into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
date    id  cat1_score1 cat2_score1 cat5_score1 cat7_score1 cat8_score1 cat1_score2 cat2_score2 cat5_score2 cat7_score2 cat8_score2
1/1/17  google    51        592         55           0            0            531       152        255           0         0
1/1/17  yahoo      0        0            0          597          58             0         0          0           357        58
1/2/17  google    71        792        795           0            0            751       352        455           0         0
1/2/17  yahoo      0         0           0          77           798            0         0          0           957        358
```

The caveat here is that the number of categories can vary from `id` to `id`. There could also potentially be a secondary ID column which would need to be considered. 
I could `enumerate` over the values in the `id` column but then how would I transform the dataframe accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's reshape like this:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['date', 'id', 'category']).stack().unstack([2, 3]).fillna(0)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df_out = df_out.add_prefix('cat').reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
         date      id  cat1_Score1  cat1_Score2  cat2_Score1  cat2_Score2  \
0  2017-01-01  google         51.0        531.0        592.0        152.0   
1  2017-01-01   yahoo          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   
2  2017-01-02  google         71.0        751.0        792.0        352.0   
3  2017-01-02   yahoo          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   

   cat5_Score1  cat5_Score2  cat7_Score1  cat7_Score2  cat8_Score1  \
0         55.0        255.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   
1          0.0          0.0        597.0        357.0         58.0   
2        795.0        455.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   
3          0.0          0.0         77.0        957.0        798.0   

   cat8_Score2  
0          0.0  
1         58.0  
2          0.0  
3        358.0
```

*Explanation:*  First `set_index` on everything but scoring columns, then use `stack` to align all the scores vertically.  Next, use `unstack` to pivot category and score labels to columns and `fillna` with zeroes.  Use columns `map` to combine column levels into one level and `add_prefix` 'cat' to columns. Lastly, `reset_index` get all columns back into the dataframe from index.

Comment: Thanks @Scott - this appears to have removed `date` and `id` from the dataframe columns though

Comment: You can reset_index a the end to get those back into the dataframe.

Comment: @Craig Thank you, and you're welcome.  Happy coding!